# Is $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ elementarily equivalent with $(\mathbb{R}, +)$?

Tags: logic, model-theory

How can I decide if $\mathbb{Q}$ is elementarily equivalent with $\mathbb{R}$ for the language that only consists of the 2-ary function symbol +? And how can I prove it?

My idea was that they are indeed elementarily equivalent, but I don't see how I can prove this.

Comment: See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563/example-of-non-isomorphic-structures-which-are-elementarily-equivalent?rq=1).